# Concatenating instance methods i.e. var.method1.method2

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write two instance methods, where method2 could process the output of method1.

For example, something like this:

```
puts Numbers::new(2,2).sum.sqrt

>16
```

I thought that the code would look something like this:

```
class Numbers

  def initialize(x,y)
    @x=x
    @y=y    
  end

  def sum
    @z=@x+@y
  end

  def sqrt
    @z**2
  end

end
```

That is not the case and I get a NoMethodError when I try to call sqrt.

I know I am missing something easy and fundamental here, but I couldn't find a straight answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The `sum` method returns the value of `@z` which is a `Fixnum`. Ruby is trying to execute the `sqrt` method on the `Fixnum` instance and hence the exception.

May be this is what you want:

```
class Fixnum
  def square
    self**2
  end
end

class Array
  def sum
    reduce(0, &:+)
  end
end
```

Now you can:

```
[1,2].sum.square # 9
```

Comment: Adding these methods to the core classes that best represent what you're trying to do sounds like a much better plan than creating your own class that has almost zero features.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu, thank you. I was specifically interested in making method1 return an instance that can be processed by method2, so I am going to try the suggestion by Dave below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to call an instance method, you need an instance--your sum method needs to return the instance to allow chaining (same with sqrt).

Method chaining is common, but IMO a bit counter-intuitive in this case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? How do I make method return an instance?

Comment: @eLi. Just "return self". Remember in Ruby that a method returns the value of its last statement, as Kandada said, in this case, sum returns z. (You don't need an explicit return in Ruby; you could just write "self" as the last statement.) IMO his code makes more sense, too, but it depends on what you're really trying to do.

Comment: As far as what I am trying to do: I have a set of data that I am taking through several steps of analysis. I have some utility for the output at each individual step, so I wanted to have a way to save each output individually. Intuitively, I thought that making a class with multiple methods (a method for each step) would be a neat way to go about it. So that I can do things like DATA::new(path).step1.step2.stepN when I wanted the final result, or just DATA::new(path).step1.step2 when I only wanted output of step2.

Comment: @eLi. I suspect adding the methods to the data type as the other answer suggested is cleaner, then, although it's really a stylistic/cognitive preface... It's just cleaner.

Comment: I see. I am somewhat of a novice, so just to make sure I understood correctly. "Adding the methods to the data type" would be approach KandadaBoggu suggested. IE if step1 returns a hash, go into Ruby's Hash class and add a method for step2. If step 2 returns an array, go into Array class and add method for step3. This way I could chain the steps like I wanted.

Comment: @eLi. Well, yes, but once you start mixing return types, it gets confusing to use a fluid interface, since only certain orderings of method calls would be valid, unless you detect and convert data types.

Comment: In my case it's entirely linear, there is only one way to order returns. I wanted some practice making classes, and you guys clarified a lot of my questions tonight. Thank you!~